# Push array into array methodical (with map)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that I successfully map, creating new arrays. Now I would like to create a master one containing all smaller arrays. I understand you can push it in. But is there a better (less code) way to do it?

Here is my code:

```js
 obj = {
      data: [ 
        {
          temp: 1,
          air: 2,
          cloud: 3
        },
        {
          temp: 100,
          air: 101,
          cloud: 102
        }
      ]
    };
    
/*
    var temp = obj.data.map(a => a.temp); // middle step
    var air = obj.data.map(a => a.air); // middle step
        
    var OneArrayToRuleThemAll = [];
    OneArrayToRuleThemAll.push(temp,air);
    
    console.log(OneArrayToRuleThemAll);
*/

// It may be easier for you to understand, when I simply comment out half of the // code and get straight to expected result.
```

Expected result: a new array that will contain:

```
[
  [
    1,
    100
  ],
  [
    2,
    101
  ]
]
```

In other words: can I somehow map/ loop through main obj and **create OneArrayToRuleThemAll without middle steps**?

**My expected outcome is supposed to be the same as OneArrayToRuleThemAll - achieved without middle steps.**

Thanks

Comment: what kind of result you want ?

Comment: @AbdeslemCharif "In other words: can I somehow map/ loop through main obj and **create OneArrayToRuleThemAll without middle steps**?"

Comment: what is your expected outcome

Comment: @Durga given that there is no code to begin with, no, [CodeReview.SE] is not the better place. Please [have a look at the  guide for SO users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: @Zeta there is code!

Comment: As it stands, your current "code" is commented out.

Comment: @Zeta it is, to make it clearer for others to comprehend the expected outcome without focusing on middle part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array for the keys and transpose the array to the wanted style.

```js
var obj = { data: [{ temp: 1, air: 2, cloud: 3 }, { temp: 100, air: 101, cloud: 102 }] },
    keys = ['temp', 'air'],
    result = obj.data.reduce(
        (r, o) => (keys.forEach((k, i) => (r[i] = (r[i] || [])).push(o[k])), r),
        []
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  var temp = []
  var air = []
  var OneArrayToRuleThemAll = []
  var length = obj.data.length
  var count = 0
  obj.data.map( (o) => {
    count ++
    temp.push(o.temp)
    air.push(o.air)
    if (count == length){
      OneArrayToRuleThemAll.push(temp, air)
    }
  })
```

Comment: That is pretty much, the same approach - creating the middle Arrays and pushing it in...

Comment: I would like to have the same result as in the question, without creating middle arrays. In other words map/loop through main obj and create OneArrayToRuleThemAll with the same output as per question.

Comment: do I really need to make var temp and var air? No, - I want to get straight to final array containing them two as per question.